# How to tag primary community to a node in network analysis

Tags: python, networkx

So I am using networkX in Python to generate a community map, and now I want to tag each node with it's primary community. Here is the code I use:

```
parts = community.best_partition(G_fb)
values = [parts.get(node) for node in G_fb.nodes()]
plt.axis("off")
nx.draw_networkx(G_fb, pos = spring_pos, cmap = plt.get_cmap("jet"), node_color = values, node_size = 35, with_labels = False)
```

Anyone knows how to tag this information?

Comment: What do you mean by `tag`? Node labels can be created with `networkx.draw_networkx_node_labels`, IIRC.

Comment: Do you mean I should set with_labels = True? But this will produce a graph, how can I save it as a network data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [set_node_attribute](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html?highlight=set_node_attributes#networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes) function from networkx. Just get the correct syntax based on your networkx version ( I am using 2.1)

```
import networkx as nx
import community

G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(30, 0.05)

#Compute the partition
partition = community.best_partition(G)

nx.set_node_attributes(G, partition, 'best_community')

#Then you access each node to get the property
my_nodes = G.nodes()
my_nodes[0]
#{ 'best_community' : 0 }
```

**Update** Based on your comments, you are getting an error because you don't have node numbered `0` in your nodes list, try any node from you `data` like `my_nodes[1229400064]`

Comment: I tested the code with my data but the my_nodes[0] prompts an error saying "KeyError: 0". I can run my_nodes but not with index included. But this error doesn't occur with your data.

Comment: Can you share a link to your dataset ?

Comment: Here, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ezk1LjGrqT1b49TNlSYDawx28oLe0bus7WFHSjfYD14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am getting a memory error after reading your data. I think your data is too large. Can you add the output of `print len(G.nodes())` after reading your data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173508/discussion-between-james-xiang-and-mohammed-kashif).